# How to conditionally define if an image/table should take one or two columns based on a predefined width

Tags: graphics, positioning

First time I post a question here, and I want to thank you in advance for your help ;)
Moving on to my problem, I would like to do the following:

```
\newcommand{\my_image_width}{300}
###
###
###
if(\my_image_width > \columnwidth){
    \begin{figure*}[htc]
        \begin{center}
           \includegraphics[width=\my_image_width pt]{path/to/my/image.png}
           \caption[]{My figure occupies two columns}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure*}
}
else{
    \begin{figure}[htc]
        \begin{center}
           \includegraphics[width=\my_image_width pt]{path/to/my/image.png}
           \caption[]{My figure occupies one column}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure}
}
```

Please keep in mind that this could be either an image or a table. Just to clarify, my main question is how to use this kind of "if" against the columnwidth and a variable.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX - LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider the command `\Figure[][]{}{}` which will take four arguments, in which first option is optional. The macro will put the image with scale parameter inside a box and if the width of the box is greater than the `\columnwidth`, then `figure*` will be used instead of `figure` environment. Arguments of the macro:

1. Key-value options to scale the figure, alignment of the figure, various vertical skips such as above, middle and below skip of figure can be provided through this option.
2. The position of the float.
3. Name of the figure.
4. Caption text.

You can give the following key-value options:

1. `scale`: to scale the image
2. `align`: value should be `centering`, `raggedleft` or `raggedright`.
3. `aboveskip`: skip above the image
4. `middleskip`: skip between image and caption
5. `belowskip`: skip below the image

   ```
   \documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

   \RequirePackage{xkeyval}
   \RequirePackage{graphicx}
   \RequirePackage{lipsum}

   \makeatletter
   \fboxsep=0pt\fboxrule=1pt
   \def\fig@default{%
     \def\fig@scale{1}%
     \def\fig@align{centering}%
     \def\fig@aboveskip{0pt}%
     \def\fig@belowskip{0pt}%
     \def\fig@middleskip{10pt}%
   }
   \define@key{fig}{scale}{\def\fig@scale{#1}}
   \define@key{fig}{align}{\def\fig@align{#1}}
   \define@key{fig}{aboveskip}{\def\fig@aboveskip{#1}}
   \define@key{fig}{belowskip}{\def\fig@belowskip{#1}}
   \define@key{fig}{middleskip}{\def\fig@middleskip{#1}}
   \def\Figure{\@ifnextchar[{\@Figure}{\@Figure[scale=1]}}
   \def\@Figure[#1][#2]#3#4{\fig@default%
     \setkeys{fig}{#1}%
     \global\setbox0\hbox{\includegraphics[scale=\fig@scale]{#3}}%
     \ifdim\the\wd0>\the\columnwidth%
       \xdef\fig@env{figure*}%
     \else%
       \xdef\fig@env{figure}%
     \fi%
     \begin{\fig@env}[#2]%
     \expandafter\csname\fig@align\endcsname%
     \vskip\fig@aboveskip%
     \fbox{\includegraphics[scale=\fig@scale]{#3}}%
     \vskip\fig@middleskip%
     \caption{#4}%
     \vskip\fig@belowskip%
     \end{\fig@env}%
   }
   \makeatother

   \begin{document}

   \lipsum[1-4]

   \Figure[scale=.3,align=raggedleft,middleskip=1pc][b!]{example-image}{Test caption.}

   \Figure[scale=1][t!]{example-image}{Test caption.}

   \lipsum

   \Figure[scale=.3,align=raggedleft,middleskip=1pc][b!]{example-image}{Test caption.}

   \lipsum[1-20]

   \end{document}
   ```

Similarly you could define a macro for tables.